# Confused about storyboards and pushing programmatically ios Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am really confused about the relationship between storyboards and pushing to views programmatically.

I am using SWRevealViewController to display a menu of items.

If I push to the storyboard using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PhotosViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotosViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

All of the information in my storyboard is displayed but there is no "back" button to the SWRevealViewController.

If I push to the view controller using

```
PhotosViewController *frontViewController = [[StreamScreen alloc] init];
    newFrontController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
```

Then I can view everything that I have added programmatically but nothing from the storyboard.

My question is how can I access things from both storyboard and things Ive added programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you present the view controller then it will not give you default back button because when you present a controller it will not added in navigation stack of NavigationController so it won't give you that option.

If you want push controller do not use **presentModalViewController**.

Try like below

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PhotosViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotosViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and if you want to present controller then create manually add a back button like we have default in navigation back button and on it's click write below code to dismiss the controller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for this code. I am now one step further. Now I see my screen for a split second and then the screen turns black. Any ideas why this is? Thank you again.

Comment: have to see your code for that to better give you answer.
Reason may be : You push to second controller twice

Comment: and If my answer solve your posted question. please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: You were 100% correct, I was pushing to second view controller twice. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help you... Code and Enjoy.. Objective C